# The usage of "humor"

Tags: word-usage

Can the word "humor" be used  in the sense of "to entertain"? Dictionaries use the word " to please" as synonym.

For example:

Does the first following sentence have the same meaning the second one?

> I like to watch movies that humor me.
>
> I like to watch movies that entertain me/ make me laugh.

Comment: A common phrase is "Don't humor me" when you want someone to be serious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. When used as a verb, humor means to indulge someone or put up with them. From Merriam-Webster:

To soothe or content (someone) by indulgence : to comply with the temperament or inclinations of

```
The only way to get along with him is to humor him.

I know you don't agree, but just humor me.
```

Comment: Therefore, can we say  the first sentence does not make a sense much?

Comment: No, it doesn't make that much sense, but I would understand that you had meant to say "I like to watch movies that are humorous" or "I like to watch movies that are full of humor."

Comment: If you tried to apply the word's legitimate usage to the first sentence, you might come up with an idea like, "I like movies that cater to my viewpoint, even when I suspect the movie makers don't really agree with me." But as Nicholas said, you'd probably just guess at a different meaning instead.